# Oracle SQL "column ambiguously defined" with `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query `SELECT A.ID, B.ID FROM A, B` that works fine.
As soon as I add `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` to it, the query fails with the error message

> SQL Error [918] [42000]: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

As far as I understand, the error refers to an ambiguous `SELECT` clause and should not be caused by a `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`.

**Do I miss something that justifies this behaviour? Or is this a bug?**

I know that I can omit this behaviour when I specify an explicit column alias. I want to know, why `SELECT A.ID, B.ID FROM A, B` works, while `SELECT A.ID, B.ID FROM A, B FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY` doesn't.

The Oracle version is 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: Tip of today: Use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Is this the whole query or did you remove/redacted something before posting?

Comment: This is the whole query. I changed only the identifiers.

Comment: actually, I noticed the behaviour on a differnet query, but I stripped it down to this one.

Comment: `...FROM A, B...` with no qualifying conditions in a WHERE clause is a cross join, meaning every row in A is joined to every row in B. Just thinking that this may not be what was intended...  Also, [works fine in 18c - dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc8679e32792d60d161782f0bb446f1d)

Comment: @BobJarvis I removed the conditions for a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is documented in [oracle documents](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABHFGAA):

> **Restrictions on the row_limiting_clause**
>
> If the select list contains columns with identical names and you
>   specify the row_limiting_clause, then an ORA-00918 error occurs. This
>   error occurs whether the identically named columns are in the same
>   table or in different tables. You can work around this issue by
>   specifying unique column aliases for the identically named columns.

Even though `SELECT` query works, after using `FETCH FIRST|NEXT`, it will throw error if two of the column names are same.

You should just assign different alias names for all columns in `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Interesting. [Per the 18c SQL Reference Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABHFGAA) this restriction still exists in 18c - but per [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc8679e32792d60d161782f0bb446f1d) it works just fine. Is a puzzlement...

Comment: You never know what stands behind dbfiddle. It does not have to be the original Oracle compiler.

Comment: Seems to be a very arbitrary restriction. I wonder where it comes from...

Comment: @Qw3ry Because Oracle wraps the whole thing with SELECT * FROM ( your original query ) WHERE ROWNUM <= ?`  Not _exactly_ that (I think it adds a `row_number()` expression instead of using `ROWNUM`), but the point is the same: your original query becomes an inline view.  That's where the `ORA-00918` comes from if the column names aren't unique.

Comment: Not fixed in 19C https://www.oraexcel.com/database-oracle-18cR1-ORA-00918

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard* `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  But that is not your problem.

You have two columns with the same alias.  Simply use `as` to assign new aliases:

```
SELECT A.ID as a_id, B.ID as b_id
```

What you are observing may be a bug.  The code seems to work on other versions of Oracle.

Comment: Why should one not use commas in the `FROM` clause? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Jagger, Using commas in the FROM clause, is not ANSI standard. It is not recommended. The disadvantages of , based JOIN clause is documented [Please use ANSI JOIN Sytax ORACLE FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2618)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know how I can avoid the error. I edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: @VenkataramanR, Comma separated tables in the FROM clause is valid ANSI/ISO SQL. Will probably never be deprecated. (However, still bad programming practice to use it.)

Comment: @jarlh, yes. it was old ANSI standard. It was revised in ANSI JOIN syntax 92, it seems. SQL Server has deprecated it long back. ORACLE has not deprecated it. I agree with you, that it might not be deprecated. but, it is better to use new JOIN syntax for new developments as a good programming practice and avoid rework, in case it gets deprecated.

Comment: @Jagger: it's very, very easy to misconstrue what is meant when the join conditions are all lumped into the WHERE clause. Add in the Oracle outer-join ( "(+)" ) syntax and life can get...interesting. (The Historians Curse ("May you live in interesting times") applies :-).